# Error: Could not find or load main class Maven Spring Boot Application - Executable JAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to run an executable jar but got the following message :

```
Could not find or load main class
```

Here is the content of MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Built-By: Administrator
Build-Jdk: 11.0.3
Class-Path: spring-boot-starter-batch-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar spring-boot-starter-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar spring-boot-autocon
     figure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar .......
Main-Class: EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter.App
```

I am really stuck as I searched the web, tried many solutions to make my executable JAR run!

Please help, I sent over 5 hours trying to fix with no luck!

here is my POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter</groupId>
    <artifactId>EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter</name>
    <description>EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter.App</mainClass>
        <layout>jar</layout>
        <outputDirectory>../libs</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the command that you are using to execute the jar

Comment: java -jar EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Main-Class: EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter.App . Is this the correct package and class name of main class?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217002/how-do-i-tell-spring-boot-which-main-class-to-use-for-the-executable-jar   Check if this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to spring boot application you can't create a regular jar file, because spring boot application jar is not a jar at all. It doesn't have an internal directory layout of jar (all dependencies are in BOOT-INF/lib for example) and there are some other subtle differences.

So I believe the issue is with maven here.

Instead of trying to create jar "by youself" and  add all the dependencies there you should use [spring boot maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html):

It "knows" how to create a spring boot jar properly.
By default it will also resolve your "main" file (the one with method `main` and `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) however you can specify it in plugin configuration to be on the safe side.

Then you'll be able to the project with :

```
java -jar <Name_of_your_jar>
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your solution but I got the following message when I run the jar 

"no main manifest attribute, in EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Comment: have you removed all other plugins from pom? open the jar with WinRar and check what's inside

Comment: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
EAB/
EAB/ActiveTeam/
EAB/ActiveTeam/Exporter/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter/
META-INF/maven/EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter/EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter/
EAB/ActiveTeam/Exporter/App.class
EAB/ActiveTeam/Exporter/CustomerItemProcessor.class
META-INF/maven/EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter/EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter/EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter/pom.xml
EAB/ActiveTeam/Exporter/BatchConfiguration$1$1.class
EAB/ActiveTeam/Exporter/BatchConfiguration.class
EAB/ActiveTeam/Exporter/BatchConfiguration$1.class

Comment: the above is the jar contents

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.1
Built-By: Administrator
Build-Jdk: 11.0.3

Comment: The above is the content of 
Manifest.MF

Comment: Try generating spring boot app from start.spring.io and check the pom.xml that it has, find the differences with yours and see what's wrong, I'm sure about the reason, but without seeing the actual pom its hard to reason. I see from your comments that `. no boot-inf lib folder => dependencie are not picked, this is wrong. 2. Manifest mf is wrong (again compare with the one generated by start.spring.io)

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin
:2.2.1.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project EAB.ActiveTeam.Exporter: Unable
to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin
:2.2.1.RELEASE:repackage: Cannot convert 'jar' to Enum: No enum constant org.spr
ingframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.LayoutType.jar -> [Help 1]

Comment: You've configured the spring-boot-maven-plugin wrong this time

Comment: post your pom.xml as it looks now in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203413/discussion-between-anas-tina-and-mark-bramnik).