# Jar built from Gradle multi-module project with Spring Boot doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

I created spring-boot gradle multi-module project which consisted of 3 modules: controller, service, repository. Main file was situated in Controller-module and named MySpringBootApplication.

I could build this project (using gradle build) and could get jar-file. But after starting this jar in command line I took the next error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.epam.esm.config.MySpringBootApplication Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.epam.esm.config.MySpringBootApplication.
```

To fix this bug I added `Main-Class` attributte to *MANIFEST.MF* file in main `build.gradle` but this action didn't help. So could anybody help?

MAIN BUILD.GRADLE FILE

```
        plugins {
            id 'java'
            id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
            id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
            id 'application'
        }
        
        group = 'com.myproject'
        version = 'snapshot-1.0.0'
        
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        
        bootJar {
            enabled = false
        }
        
        jar {
            enabled = true
            manifest {
                attributes(
                        "Main-Class": "com.myproject.config.MySpringBootApplication")
            }
        }
       
     dependencies {
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
            implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.4.3', ext: 'pom'
        
        }
        
        test {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
        
        
        subprojects {
            apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
            apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
            apply plugin: 'java'
        
            group = 'com.epam.esm'
            version = '1.0.0'
        
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }
            bootJar {
                enabled = false
            }
        
            jar {
                enabled = true
            }
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
                implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
                implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
                implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
                implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
                testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
                implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: '5.4.27.Final'
                implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
                implementation group: 'org.openidentityplatform.commons', name: 'json-web-token', version: '2.0.11'
                compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.18'
                annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
                implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
                implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.4.3', ext: 'pom'
            }
            test {
                useJUnitPlatform()
            }
        }
```

SETTINGS.GRADLE

```
    rootProject.name = 'module'
    include('repository', 'service', 'controller')
```

Comment: Your application module should have `bootJar { enabled =true }`

Comment: it doesn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Spring Boot* application executable jar file is built by `bootJar` task, so adding the main-class information via `jar` won't work either.

> The `bootJar` task tries to create an executable jar, and that
> requires a main() method. As a result, you need to disable the
> `bootJar` task and enable the jar task (which creates an ordinary jar
> rather than an executable jar) only for your no executable jar
> modules.

Since you did it under `subprojects` section, the `controller` module will produce a standard *jar* as well. You may produce standard *jars* for all modules but excluding the `controller` module as follows:

```
subprojects {
    
    if (it.name != 'controller') {
        bootJar {
            enabled = false
        }

        jar {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

In addition you have to remove the `jar` section below

```
 jar {
        enabled = true
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    "Main-Class": "com.myproject.config.MySpringBootApplication")
        }
    }
```

and replace

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
```

with

```
    bootJar {
        mainClassName = 'com.myproject.config.MySpringBootApplication'
    }
```

Reference

[Creating a Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)

Comment: You are great!!!! I couldn't find answer for some days but you gave it during half an hour after publishing a question. Thank you.