# maven build Failed to execute goal

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Good day.I'm running into a strange error when trying `mvn clean install -Drat.skip=true`

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>petclinic-data</module>
        <module>petclinic-web</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.petclinic</groupId>
    <artifactId>petclinic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>petclinic</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <scm>
        <url>scm:git:git@github.com:h1dd33n/petClinic.git</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:h1dd33n/petClinic.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>
            scm:git:git@github.com:h1dd33n/petClinic.git
        </developerConnection>
      <tag>petclinic-0.0.1</tag>
  </scm>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>

<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <excludes>-->
<!--                        <exclude>-->
<!--                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>-->
<!--                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>-->
<!--                        </exclude>-->
<!--                    </excludes>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <checkModificationExcludes>pom.xml</checkModificationExcludes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Child POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>petclinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.petclinic</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>petclinic-data</artifactId>
  <version>yes</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The Error

> Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:repackage
> (repackage) on project petclinic-data: Execution repackage of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:repackage
> failed: Unable to find main class

Comment: Duplicate Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217002/how-do-i-tell-spring-boot-which-main-class-to-use-for-the-executable-jar

Comment: That can not work because you have configuration to skip the spring-boot-maven-plugin which is wrong. Remove that configuration and try `mvn package` (`install` is not necessary).. And of course define